# Need Help sending data from AS3 to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, phpmyadmin

I have a form which is created in Adobe flash actionscript 3 and need help to verify if what i'm doing is correct... i'm new to both AS3 and PHP so any help and explanation would be really appreciated...

here is my AS3 coding....

```
processing_mc.visible = false;

function checkComplete(evt:MouseEvent):void {

    // Create A new URLVariables instance to store the variable
    var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

    // Create a variable (e.g. candidate) to send
    phpVars.userFirstName = firstname_txt.text;
    phpVars.userLastName = lastname_txt.text;
    phpVars.userNumber = number_txt.text;
    phpVars.userEmail = email_txt.text; 
    phpVars.userMsg = msg_txt.text;

    // Create a new URLRequest instance sending data to "ascom01.php"
    var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("form.php");
    // Send data using the POST method
    myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.load(myRequest);

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, response);
function response(e:Event):void
{
    trace(loader.data);
}

if(!firstname_txt.length) {
status_txt.text = "Please enter your first name";
} else if(!lastname_txt.length) {
status_txt.text = "Please enter your last name";
} else if (!email_txt.length) {
status_txt.text = "Please enter your email";
} else if (!number_txt.length) {
status_txt.text = "Please enter your phone number";
} else {

}

}
// handler for the PHP script completion and return of status
function completeHandler(event:Event):void {

processing_mc.visible = false;
firstname_txt.text = "";
lastname_txt.text = "";
email_txt.text = "";
number_txt.text = "";
msg_txt.text = "";

status_txt.text = event.target.data.return_msg;
}

// Add event listener for submit button click
submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkComplete);
```

And here is my PHP coding which i just got to work....

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['userFirstName']) && isset($_POST['userLastName']) && isset($_POST['userEmail']) && isset($_POST['userNumber']) && isset($_POST['userMsg']))
{
    $userFirstName=strip_tags($_POST['userFirstName']);
    $userLastName=strip_tags($_POST['userLastName']);
    $userEmail=strip_tags($_POST['userEmail']);
    $userNumber=strip_tags($_POST['userNumber']);
    $userMsg=strip_tags($_POST['userMsg']);

    // connect with database. 

    $username="******";
    $password="******";
    $database="b-elite-fitness";

    mysql_connect("localhost","$username","$password") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("$database") or die (mysql_error());

    //query for inserting data in database.
    $query="INSERT INTO `formdp` VALUES('NULL','".mysql_real_escape_string($userFirstName)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($userLastName)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($userEmail)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($userNumber)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($userMsg)."')";

    if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
    {
        echo'Data inserted.';
    } else {
        die(mysql_error());
        }


}
?>
```

can anyone help me with the connection between the two... I've checked online and every example is different and cant understand how it works....

Thanks in advance DP

Comment: you shouldnt be posting passwords ...

Comment: you should change your password as anyone can still view them by looking at the edit history =b

Comment: yeah I'll do that thanks!... but can anyone help with the problem in hand? connect AS3 to PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

If by connect you mean send the data from AS3 to PHP, you want to use the [`URLLoader`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) class.

You already have the data ready to go with your `URLRequest` instance above, so all that is left to do is for you to send that data off through a `URLLoader`:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(myRequest);
```

You can manage a response from your PHP script by attaching a listener for [`Event.COMPLETE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event%3acomplete) to the `URLLoader`. The response will be stored within its [`data`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#data) property:

```
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, response);
function response(e:Event):void
{
    trace(loader.data);
}
```

Comment: where abouts in my coding would i add this ? 

Im new to AS3 and PHP so a bit confused... the var loader would go below the urlrequest correct ? and where would the loader function go in my script ? 

DP 

Thank you

Comment: ok i got the coding to compile correctly, however when i enter data into the form it wont send to mysql even tho the connection between php and mysql is correct and after entering your coding that as3 and php is connected as well ? where would the probelm lay...?

Comment: by any chance could you help? I've looked at my coding in the php file and i am sure that the query is correct and the data should be entered into the database... but of course it doesn't send... I'm really stuck at this point as i have no clue what the problem could be....?
DP

Comment: Did you check that you PHP script is called? If yes, did you check the content of the `$_POST` variable so that it contains the data entered in the AS3 form?
On the actionscript side, do you get any events after `loader.load(myRequest);` has been called?
With no more details, it will be hard for people to help you.

Comment: how do i check if the php is called ? with a trace ? how do i check the content of the $_POST? I'm new to both PHP and AS3... what more details can i provide...? if i can send someone my files to check over the coding i would appreciate it alot... but i would rather learn how the coding is working and understand it... I've updated to the coding above to what works so far @MartyWallace

Comment: @DP187 Do you see anything in the output window a short while after you submit the form? The trace that I have in my example should be resulting in something (at least the mysql error for example).

Comment: @MartyWallace in the output window in adobe flash i get the php coding :S its confusing...? i get all my coding from the php file? should that happen?

Comment: @DP187 No. That means the PHP script isn't actually executing. Are you certain that your PHP script is hosted on a platform (web server) that supports PHP? I have a feeling that the PHP file is in your documents / on your desktop somewhere and not actually in an environment that will execute the PHP script.

Comment: @DP187 Have you got a local web server installed with PHP? If not, I suggest installing [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) before continuing with your learning of PHP.

Comment: yes i have wampserver 2.2 and I've put all files in the same folder and that folder is in the WWW of the wamp documents is there any difference between xampp and wamp ?